# How to get data from other table within a group by query?

Tags: sql-server

I have tried to group records from one table which have similar SerialNo. And I also want to show a column records from other table that has relation ship with table one using SerialNo.

**I have a table 1:**

[image]

**And table 2:**

[image]

**My Query is:**

```
select CIT_SERIALNUMBER, COUNT(CIT_ID)
 as Cases from Table_2 where CIT_SOURCEID like '%E_One%'
 and (CIT_CREATED BETWEEN '2018-01-15'AND '2019-06-15') and CIT_SERIALNUMBER is not null
   group by CIT_SERIALNUMBER
  having COUNT(CIT_ID)>1 order by  min(CIT_CREATED) desc
```

**Here is the result table:**

[image]

In the query above I’ve got only **CIT_SERIALNUMBER** records from **Table_2**. But I also want to get the data from **Table_1** column **ComputerName**. So, the expected result is:

[image]

*Note: The two table 1 and 2 can be join by Column T1_Serial and CIT_SERIALNUMBER.*

Please help me to re-write the sql query to achieve the expected result above.

Comment: Don't use images. To show tables' structure post `CREATE TABLE` statements. Also add sample data using `INSERT INTO` statements.

Comment: Sure @stickybit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your column names correctly, try this:

```
select CIT_SERIALNUMBER, ComputerName, COUNT(CIT_ID)
 as Cases from Table_2 join Table_1 on Table_2.CIT_SERIALNUMBER=Table_1.Serial where CIT_SOURCEID like '%E_One%'
 and (CIT_CREATED BETWEEN '2018-01-15'AND '2019-06-15') and CIT_SERIALNUMBER is not null
   group by CIT_SERIALNUMBER
  having COUNT(CIT_ID)>1 order by  min(CIT_CREATED) desc
```

Comment: It will generate an error:
Column 'ComputerName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT A.ComputerName,
CIT_SERIALNUMBER, 
COUNT(CIT_ID) AS Cases
FROM table_1 A
INNER JOIN Table_2 B ON A.Column T1_Serial = CIT_SERIALNUMBER.
WHERE B.CIT_SOURCEID LIKE '%E_One%'
      AND (B.CIT_CREATED BETWEEN '2018-01-15' AND '2019-06-15')
      AND B.CIT_SERIALNUMBER IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A.ComputerName,B.CIT_SERIALNUMBER
HAVING COUNT(B.CIT_ID) > 1
ORDER BY MIN(B.CIT_CREATED) DESC;
```

Comment: The query return not only records from table A, but also rows that match table B. But I only want records from table A.

Comment: As you are combining selection and filtering of records between 2 tables, its normal that the query will work with all matched records from both tables.

Comment: Yes. I'm finding a way to group all similar records from table A. But I also want view a column from table B which has relationship with table A via Serial Number in result set.

Comment: I have another query:

`SELECT y.CIT_SERIALNUMBER, y.Cases, x.ComputerName
    FROM Table_1 x
    right JOIN (
 select CIT_SERIALNUMBER, COUNT(CIT_ID)
 as Cases from Table_2 where CIT_SOURCEID like '%E_One%'
 and (CIT_CREATED BETWEEN '2018-01-15'AND '2019-06-15') and CIT_SERIALNUMBER is not null
   group by CIT_SERIALNUMBER
  having COUNT(CIT_ID)>1 order by  min(CIT_CREATED) desc
  ) y ON y.CIT_SERIALNUMBER = x.T1_Serial`

Comment: And got an error message:

The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Bring the order by query out of sub query - SELECT y.CIT_SERIALNUMBER, 
       y.Cases, 
       x.ComputerName
FROM Table_1 x
     RIGHT JOIN
(
    SELECT CIT_SERIALNUMBER, 
           COUNT(CIT_ID) AS Cases
    FROM Table_2
    WHERE CIT_SOURCEID LIKE '%E_One%'
          AND (CIT_CREATED BETWEEN '2018-01-15' AND '2019-06-15')
          AND CIT_SERIALNUMBER IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY CIT_SERIALNUMBER
    HAVING COUNT(CIT_ID) > 1   
) y ON y.CIT_SERIALNUMBER = x.T1_Serial
ORDER BY MIN(CIT_CREATED) DESC;

Answer (score 0):

It look odd, but I've got a solution for this:

- I select all duplicated records from Table_2 first
- Then I join Table_1 with result set of Table_2 to view column from both tables
- Then I use another select to select data from result set above and group by all records.

Here is the query:

```
select z.CIT_SERIALNUMBER, z.ComputerName, z.Cases from (
SELECT y.CIT_SERIALNUMBER, x.ComputerName, y.Cases
    FROM Table_1 x
    right JOIN (
      select CIT_SERIALNUMBER, COUNT(CIT_ID)
 as Cases from Table_2 where CIT_SOURCEID like '%E_One%'
 and (CIT_CREATED BETWEEN '2018-01-15'AND '2019-06-15') and CIT_SERIALNUMBER is not null
   group by CIT_SERIALNUMBER
  having COUNT(CIT_ID)>1 
  ) y ON y.CIT_SERIALNUMBER = x.SerialNo) z  group by CIT_SERIALNUMBER, z.ComputerName, z.Cases
```

Result set:

[image]